# How do you get only one output from a swi-prolog query?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel, prolog-setof

How do I get only one output from a SWI-Prolog query? I have tried using cut (`!`) but it does not seem to work.

For example: 
I already filled my knowledge base up with statements and I wanted to find any one name who is both female and is the mother of someone.

I have already tried:

```
mother(X,Y), female(X).
```

...but that gives me all of the `X-__` and `Y-__`

I have also tried:

```
mother(X,Y), female(X), !.
```

... but that still gives me both the `X-__` and `Y__`

I only want to find the `X`. Does anyone have any tips for me to somehow only get one?

Comment: You're just guessing trying to use `!` (cut). :) It will just eliminate additional solutions for both `X` and `Y` resulting from backtracking. Did you try, `mother(X, _), female(X).`? The `_` means you don't care what it's value is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
?- setof(t, Y^ ( mother(X, Y), female(Y) ), _).
```

which will remove duplicates (redundant answers/solutions), too. Or using [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl):

```
?- X+\ ( mother(X, Y), female(Y) ).
```

which does not remove redundant answers.

Comment: hmm, when I tried to use the "?- X+\ ( mother(X, Y), female(Y) ).", I got a 
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: 
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: X+\(mother(X,Y),female(Y))

what does that mean?

Comment: @user3369494: You need to use `library(lambda)`, see above.

Comment: ooh, my bad. I didn't see that. Sorry! Could you explain how the first line works?